# How to create a PHP-like Winsocks app?

Tags: php

I seen Winsocks in C++ I want to do the same with php. Can anyone shed some light on the subject?

Comment: Just be sure to put on the winsocks before you try to use the winshoes.  :P  (It's actually called "winsock".)

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a sockets library, which is [fully documented](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php).  It provides very similar functionality as Winsock.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is mainly know as the language for the web development, but you would be surprised to see that it can be used to even create desktop softwares.

**[You need WinBinder to create desktop applications with PHP.](http://winbinder.org/)** Best of luck :)

Relevant Info: **[PHP Sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php)**

Answer (score 0):

As bobbymcr has said, all the basic socket and network functions (DNS lookups, long2ip etc) are exposed in PHP and well documented.

It also has functionality to cope with multiple concurrent operations (the *_select() functions).

If you are writing a server daemon, then you might find this class useful:

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/5758.html

C.